# How do you obtain an array of vlookup values without an extra column in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list and a lookup table. The list will be in column A and the lookup table will be in columns C and D. Each cell in column C contains text and is unique. Column D has a corresponding value for each element of column C. Column A contains an unsorted list with duplicates of the text from column C but nothing outside of column C. An easy example is shown below

[image: Simple Example]

What I ultimately want is an array that contains the corresponding values looked up from the table for all of column A. So in this example I want

```
{1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2}
```

I know this can be accomplished by using

```
=vlookup(B9,$C$1:$D$2,2,FALSE)
```

in each cell of column B and grab the column as an array {$B$1:$B$9}. However, I need to skip the middle man and omit having anything in another column as this needs to be performed on various lookup tables simultaneous but not connected, i.e. not a multiple lookup, I just need to look at the same list A under a different set of corresponding values D.

I'm at a complete loss, it seems so simple but I've been trying for hours and going in circles. I recall reading that you can't output vlookup to an array and I didn't have much luck trying to use match either. So really any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for that without macros.

You can't avoid using `VLOOKUP` and it can't manage array as "lookup value" parameter.

I think the best option is to use a helper column as you've already described.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to return `{1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2}` as your result. Or perhaps you really desire `1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2` and just put in the braces (`{}`) to make it look right for the discussion. Not sure which so I'll show both.

As long as I can remember, `VLOOKUP()` has been willing to take a range, or any kind of array ({"a",4,"4"} for example), for its lookup value. Might require use of `{CSE}` entry (`Ctrl-Shift-Enter`) to get a return for all members of the range being looked up, but that was always just a nuisance, not the kind of difficulty presented by, say, adding macros to a spreadsheet.

So using an array/range will work, but in 2016, I'm sure getting more than the first value for a result would have required `{CSE}`. If anyone here was trying an array/range and did not use `{CSE}`, that might've been why results were unacceptable.

In 2021 though, it is no longer necessary when using `VLOOKUP()` this way.

So now, AND IN 2018 when the second answer was posted, `TEXTJOIN()` would have worked very nicely to take the array of results the lookup returned and join them together in a nice string. In 2016, one would have used `CONCAT()`.

`CONCAT()` can take a range/array as its input. Excel will handle the range as a "single item" though you can wrap it with parentheses to ensure it does. So one can build a string in it that looks like the following:

```
=CONCAT(B9:B17&",")
```

It takes each return the range cells generate and adds the comma to each return, one by one. Then it strings each of those intermediate strings into the finished product. So the following formula would produce the basic string:

```
=CONCAT(VLOOKUP(A1:A9,C1:D2,2,FALSE)&",")
```

It ends up with a comma at the end, so to produce the array without that you'd wrap it all with a `SUBSTITUTE()` function to remove ONLY the last 0 by specifying the "instance number" using cleverness:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(VLOOKUP(A1:A9,C1:D2,2,FALSE)&","),",","",ROWS(A1:A9))
```

There are as many commas as there are results. There are as many results as the number of cells in the range given to `VLOOKUP()`. So if you use the `ROWS()` function and give it the same range, it will return the total number of commas in the result which is, of course, also the instance number of the very last comma. So `SUBSTITUTE()` only removes that comma, leaving the rest.

You now have a string that looks like your desired string except for the curly braces. If you want the string for further use, stop here. If you want the braces, use the following. However, tacking them on will NOT make it into an array:  as in, will not make it into "a real boy."

To add them, just... add them:

```
="{"&SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(VLOOKUP(A1:A9,C1:D2,2,FALSE)&","),",","",ROWS(A1:A9))&"}"
```

Standard "make a string from parts" stuff at this point.

If you did not want a string (with, or without, braces), then further work is needed. Nowadays we might use `SUBSTITUTE()` and `FILTERXML()` to turn this, or any, text string into a real array of elements instead of a single element (the text string you've made so far).

However, in any version of Excel, one can just use the original formula and the results it returned. Today, that'd be an array without special effort and could be used easily in further work. Then, probably `{CSE}` entry would have been needed. The idea is, you were not given the string like one sometimes is but rather have made it yourself. So use just the source info, the original lookup, and just (nowadays) use it as an array in other formulas just by copying the lookup and dropping it in, so to speak, as input in the further formulas, or (then), well, essentially the same.

Answer (score -1):

This is doable with a single formula in a single cell using a fairly new Excel function `TEXTJOIN`.  This works with Excel 2016 but is not recognized in Excel 2010 resulting in `#NAME?`  I don't know about Excel 2013 and would love for someone to test it.

There are better ways to achieve the result but they don't fit your constraints, so this isn't the best solution for the task but it is the solution you wanted.

The formula is:

```
="{"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A1:A9),"a",INDEX(D1:D2,MATCH("a",C1:C2,0))),"b",INDEX(D1:D2,MATCH("b",C1:C2,0)))&"}"
```

The formula above has hardcoded lookup values.  This makes it easier to predict the output but it also makes the formula more cumbersome to write and maintain as well as making it weaker than a referenced formula.

The formula below references the cell so it's not as easy to predict output but is much more flexible.

`="{"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A1:A9),C1,INDEX(D1:D2,MATCH(C1,C1:C2,0))),C2,INDEX(D1:D2,MATCH(C2,C1:C2,0)))&"}"`

Formula has been tested using a list with more than 1,000 rows without any problem and I imagine it will work all the way through Excel's  row limit.  The length of the formula scales linearly with the lookup table and can accommodate a little over 1,000 rows.  And the complexity remains constant.  Every new row on the lookup table requires an additional `SUBSTITUTE (`at the front of the formula and a `CELL, INDEX( RANGE (MATCH (CELL, RANGE, 0)))` at the end.  Nothing in the middle needs to be changed.

[image]

Comment: Your answer works for a small lookup table only, I don't think the posted example is the real one. When lookup table had 20+ rows (which is still small) your formula gets very complicated. Also you've hard-coded lookup values making editing them much more difficult.